# cruise control.NET perforce all commits ever are modifications

Tags: perforce, cruisecontrol.net

I've got a cruise control server running and successfully building my project. However, my interval trigger (set to IfModificationExists) is registering the entire changelist in the history of the database as modifications every time it tries to build, and therefore builds on every interval regardless of whether there's a new commit. Any suggestions? Here are the relevant bits of my config file:

```
<cruisecontrol>

<project name="MyProj">
<artifactDirectory>C:\CCNet\Artifacts\</artifactDirectory>

<!-- TRIGGER THE CHECK TO BUILD EVERY HOUR -->
<triggers>
  <!-- check the source control every X time for changes, 
     and run the tasks if changes are found -->
  <intervalTrigger
           name="continuous"
           seconds="3600"
           buildCondition="IfModificationExists"
           initialSeconds="5"/>
</triggers>
<workingDirectory>C:\PerforceFiles\</workingDirectory>

<!-- CHECK FOR CHANGES IN PERFORCE, EXCLUDE .CHM FILES SINCE THEY ARE CHECKED IN AS PART OF THIS BUILD -->
<sourcecontrol type="filtered">
  <sourceControlProvider type="p4">
    <view>//depot/Folder1/... //cruisecontrol_server/Folder1/..., //depot/Folder2/... //cruisecontrol_server/Folder2/..., //depot/Folder3/... //cruisecontrol_server/Folder3/..., //depot/Folder4/... //cruisecontrol_server/Folder4/...</view>
    <executable>C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>C:\PerforceFiles</workingDirectory>
    <client>cruisecontrol_server</client> <!-- this workspace's tree is equivalent to the view listed above -->
    <user>cruisecontrol</user>
    <port>myPort</port>
    <applyLabel>false</applyLabel>
    <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
    <forceSync>false</forceSync>
  </sourceControlProvider>
  <exclusionFilters>
    <pathFilter>
      <pattern>/**/*.chm</pattern>
    </pathFilter>
  </exclusionFilters>
</sourcecontrol>
```

The remainder of the file is just my tasks and publishers, which I don't think would be relevant. If there is more information you need, let me know and I'll respond as quickly as I can.

Comment: Where are you excluding the .CHM files? you need to use the **Filtered Source Control Block** --> [link](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Filtered)

Comment: If you were just referring to the comment, that was a relic from the CruiseControl example I based this file off of. I restored the .chm removal, but it still is giving me the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks right to me, this is the filtered block I'm using with **SVN** and is working properly:

```
  <sourcecontrol type="filtered">
      <sourceControlProvider type="svn">
          <executable>$(svnConsole)</executable>
          <username>username</username>
          <password>password</password>
          <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource> 
          <trunkUrl>https://trunkurl</trunkUrl>
          <workingDirectory>$(DevelopmentDir)\</workingDirectory>
      </sourceControlProvider>
      <exclusionFilters>
          <pathFilter>
              <pattern>**/AssemblyInfo.cs</pattern>
          </pathFilter>
     </exclusionFilters>
</sourcecontrol>
```

This **excludes** every **AssemblyInfo.cs** file on the trunk.
Hope this helps!